# How to change margin based on display/breakpoint in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I know it is possible to set the margin on Vuetify based on the display/breakpoints.

How can I change the following class in a way that margin-top will be 0 when the breakpoint/display is "s" or "xs" :

```
<v-text-field class="mt-5" field> </v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class="mt-sm-5 mt-0"
```

you can read it like this: use mt-5 if screen is wider than sm breakpoint, else use mt-0

Answer (score 3):

In addition of Romalex answer, [here's a full list of Breakpoint in Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service)

I know it's not the answer you want to, but I want to share another way to set the behaviour on screen using class conditional. Here's an example:

```
:class="[$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown?'class-1':'class-2']"
```

Cheers~